# How to properly set up a new user registration email? Worpress + Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to set up a letter that comes to the user after registering on the site. I'm using a custom signup form (essential addons plugin) and at first, I only got a standard WordPress email instead of a Woocommerce email.

I added a little code that I found on the forum and made sure that the Woocommerce email comes to the mail, but the standard WordPress email has not gone away. I want to leave one email that I can customize via Woocommerce and get rid of the default one. Code and screenshots are attached
`

```
function send_welcome_email_to_new_user($user_id) {
    $wc = new WC_Emails();
    $wc->customer_new_account($user_id);
  }
add_action('user_register', 'send_welcome_email_to_new_user');
```

`
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function disable_wp_new_user_notifications() {
    //Remove original user created emails
    remove_action( 'register_new_user', 'wp_send_new_user_notifications' );
    remove_action( 'edit_user_created_user', 'wp_send_new_user_notifications', 10, 2 );
    
}

add_action( 'init', 'disable_wp_new_user_notifications' );
```

Comment: add_filter( 'wp_new_user_notification_email', '__return_false');

I solved the problem with this code